# perl string to date time convert

Tags: perl, datetime, formatting

How to convert my string to date time format ?
i am facing error using below script
Please help me

### My code

```
use Time::Piece;
$asas='07/17/21 08:46:56';
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime('07/17/21 08:46:56', "%Y/%m/%d %h:%m:%s %p");
print ($t->strftime("%w\n"));
```

Answer (score 4):

- `%Y` is the full year, you only have the short year, i.e. `%y`.
- Each year has only 12 month, there's no month number 17. You have the y/m/d in a wrong order, perhaps you wanted m/d/y instead?
- Time (h:m:s) must be uppercase. We've already used the lowercase `%m` for "month", right?

```
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime('07/17/21 08:46:56', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S');
```

Comment: Thank you, your comments are perfect.

Comment: "Thank you" on Stack Overflow = upvote / accept :-)